# Is it good practice to reset all migration before deploy project to the server?

Tags: python, django, deployment, migration, django-migrations

I have two questions about best practices in deployment, related to migration.

1. I am in the middle of developing a Django project. Sometimes I have to change some previous migrations due to some changes in one of my more previous models(like renaming a model to which other models have FK_ I know the solution but it is dirty and manual). sometimes it makes lots of conflicts.

   I wonder "Is it really necessary to bother myself to resolve such conflicts when I am not at production When I can reset all migration by removing migration files and dropping SQLite DB?"
2. In development project contains many migrations which correct previous ones by changes to models(migration like rename, add a column ...). Isn't it better to reset all migrations and recreate all migrations first time I deploy the project to the server?
   I think why should create a table on the server with migrations that change models multiple times? Why shouldn't just deploy the final migrations?

I didn't find any docs for the best practices. Lots of thanks if you share ideas with references.

Comment: Dont reset the migration. you can create a new git branch, do all your changes, if everything is fine, then push to main branch and do the migration for one time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure django publishes a best practice around migrations, because it's going to always have the answer 'it depends'.

Based on my experience when you're development project is ready- I recommend zero'ing and recreating all the migrations for the project so you can start with a clean and simple history.

There is also the option to [squash migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing) although if you're history is erroneous or irrelevant- I'm not sure why you'd want that history in your project.

Comment: @chris the question is about the initial deploy of a new django app. Not subsequent migrations. Why keep all your development history? Do you really need your brand new project to know that you've changed the max_length of your char field four times? This is not a habit, it's about a first time deploy of an app. There is no reason to maintain verbose migration history that would get removed anyway when you eventually squash migrations.

Comment: I'm not sure you've actually read the question here. This is about the **first time** deployment of a django project into production. Conflating initial migrations with CI/security issues isn't offering value to your point or this question. There is no data in the database. There is no habit to form here. This step represents creating a clean 0001_initial migration for your app. You can't refactor migrations..that makes no sense.

Comment: Obviously one should not arbitrarily destroy production aware migration migration files. However this question could be restated as: "If a developer working on an app changes max_length of a particular CharField 4 times in development and generates four individual migration files, is it best to commit 4 migration files, or re-run the migrations to create one single migration file representing the change?" IMO single migration file representing the change is "Doing things the right way".